# Should I consider a static copy to be costly?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

When I'm traversing a collection, say a vector of `Point`s where `Point` is some struct that holds `x`, `y`, `z` data or something, when I need to convert these points to another type one point at at a time, should I consider it as costly as a copy?

For example, if I have a `vector<Point> v`, I obviously try to avoid:

```cpp
vector<OtherPointType> vo;
// populate v
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), vo.begin(),
   [](Point const& p) { return OtherPointType{p.x, p.y, p.z}; });
SomeOperation(vo); // Can only operate on vector<OtherPointType>
```

But, is that as expensive as doing:

```cpp
for_each(..., [](Point const& p)
{
   OtherPointType opt(p.x, p.y, p.z);
   SomeOperation(opt); // Can only operator on `OtherPointType`
});
```

?

My instinct says that because the later is a static copy without any dynamic allocations, that it shouldn't be expensive, but I figured it's important enough to ask.

Usually I can use something like `Eigen::Map` in latter case, but even there I'm still writing to two `int`s (on the stack) I think due to `Eigen::Stride` (is this even a good solution in this case?)  But then there are libraries like CGAL that don't have mapping capabilities, and I'm curious of a good approach to working with them.

Note, my work normally deals with a million points per second, so it's important that I try to reduce expensive copies as much as I can.

**Update**

To the sub-question where I was wondering whether `Eigen::Map` would be good in the latter case above:

I ran a [benchmark](https://gist.github.com/kheaactua/2077a4e5cbf7364a3bd20fcd2ad22142), and with gcc 5.4 at least, even with 100 million points, the results are too close to call.  Using `Eigen::Map` *vs* constructing an `Eigen::Vector3d` took 276 ms vs 285 ms respectively.  With fewer points though constructing took less time, which tells me the difference here is within the uncertainties and other processes that were running on my computer likely had a bigger impact.

Comment: If you have millions of points to copy, even if it's a trivial copy (not sure what you mean by static copy), it's still going to be a lot and be noticeable to just copy them. Also what about `SomeOperation`? Maybe vectorized? In that case, maybe first is not that bad.

Comment: My intuition would agree that the compiler can optimize the second case (shuffle some registers around before calling `SomeOperation`) much better than the first one (it almost surely has to actually create the vector and copy all the points). As with all performance questions though: Profile and measure.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher By "static copy", I mean that for every point, I'll be copying it's data to statically allocated memory.  _e.g.* Copy `p.x` to `op.x`, where `op.x` was statically allocated.

Comment: It's automatically allocated, not statically ;) As @MaxLanghof said, you need to measure both cases.

Comment: Thanks @MaxLanghof, what originally prompted this question is when I saw code that constructed an `Eigen::Vector3f` for every point, and I changed the code to use an `Eigen::map`, and afterwards I wasn't sure if the effort was even warranted.  Basically, at least, I removed the writing of three statically allocated floats with what I thin was two statically allocated ints.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Ya, I think you're right.  I'm going to set up a small test case in order to benchmark it.

Comment: You want to have a big case as well. A small case may not show any caching effect.

Comment: `OtherPointType opt(p);` suggests that you have a conversion constructor, and that you could also write `SomeOperation(p);` no? Maybe you could provide a conversion that actually does no copies but keeps a reference to the original point

Comment: @Matt To be clear, you are misusing "statically allocated" here. Stack variables (such as `opt`) are not statically allocated. Unless your `OtherPointType` does some extremely non-trivial things under the hood (which nobody will assume if it's supposedly just a point, i.e. some coordinates).

Comment: @user463035818 Hmm, you're right, it does imply that.  I'll change the code to not suggest that anymore.  A more realistic scenario is a PCL point that I want to sent into a CGAL function, so have to convert it into CGAL with `CGAL::Point_3(p.x, p.y, .pz)` or something.

Comment: @MaxLanghof That's a good point, I'll edit the question to fix the wording, it's also a good lesson for me.

Comment: For a (contrived) example where the former might actually be faster: If Point was a much larger object than OPT, and the SomeOperation benefits from good on-chip cacheing, pre-streaming the large Point list to a more compact OPT list might speed up the operation enough to make the copy a good thing.

Comment: The few cycles per loop that you might save I bet are dwarfed by `SomeOperation()`

Comment: Doesn't mean they're not savings. If you only _ever_ optimise the heaviest operation in your program, you stand to lose out on loads of savings. Though if you have a chance to optimise one _or_ optimise the other, the heaviest may be a better use of your time.

Comment: It might be that `SomeOperation()` keeps disturbing the cache which converting the container wholesale might benefit from. I think you have to do some actual timings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> should I consider [conversion] as costly as a copy?

As it is a different operation, not necessarily. It could be more or less costly. It is however, a reasonable to estimate it comparable to a copy.

> But, is [copying a vector] as expensive as [iterating a vector and copying each element onto an automatic variable]

Probably not.

> My instinct says that because the later is a static copy without any allocations, that it shouldn't be expensive

This is why latter is probably not as expensive as the former. But whether the latter is expensive depends on context. It is still an operation with linear asymptotic complexity, so if the vector is big, the allocation may be insignificant in comparison to the copies.

Whether something is more costly than something else on your hardware, and whether something is expensive in the context of your program, you can try to find out using a profiler.